# Optimise mysql image count and random

Tags: mysql, optimization

[image]Hello would be great if someone could help me with this.

Basically an image belongs to an album.

The query I am running is very slow and i could do with some advice on optimising.

The slow part of the query is (SELECT count(*) from album_image where album_image.album_id = al.id) as image_count so any advice on optimising would be great. I have used Explain extended to to find the issue here. I need to select a random guid id which is a random image in each album hence the inner join. I read using RAND() is not very good but am unsure if this is the best way of selecting a random image from each album

```
SELECT al.id, al.alias_title, al.title, al.hits, al.created_on, uf.real_name, uf.user_name, T.guid_id,
(SELECT count(*) from album_image where album_image.album_id = al.id) as image_count
FROM album al 
INNER JOIN (SELECT imx.id, aix.album_id, imx.guid_id FROM image imx 
                INNER JOIN album_image aix ON imx.id = aix.image_id 
                ORDER BY floor(RAND()*(SELECT count(1) FROM image))) AS T ON al.id = T.album_id             
INNER JOIN user us ON al.user_id = us.id
LEFT JOIN user_flickr uf ON us.flickr_id = uf.id
LEFT JOIN user_site uss ON us.user_site_id= uss.id
WHERE al.approved = 'Yes' AND al.visible ='1'
GROUP BY T.album_id;
```

Comment: You're using InnoDB I suppose. If yes, InnoDB is very slow for count() because it scans all the table. You can try to use MyISAM for that table or simply take your count once, store it, and use it later without recalculating your count(). Take a look here http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/12/01/count-for-innodb-tables/

Answer (score 0):

That part of the query is slow because it is executing once for every row that is returned.  You need to move the logic into the `from` clause:

```
SELECT al.id, al.alias_title, al.title, al.hits, al.created_on, uf.real_name, 
       uf.user_name, T.guid_id,
       ai.cnt as image_count
FROM album al inner join
     (SELECT imx.id, aix.album_id, imx.guid_id
      FROM image imx inner join
           album_image aix
      ON imx.id = aix.image_id 
      ORDER BY floor(RAND()*(SELECT count(1) FROM image))
     ) AS 
     ON al.id = T.album_id INNER JOIN
     user us
     ON al.user_id = us.id left join
     user_flickr uf
     ON us.flickr_id = uf.id left join
     user_site uss
     ON us.user_site_id= uss.id left join
     (select album_id, count(*) as cnt
      from album_image ai
      group by album_id
     ) ai
     on ai.album_id = al.id
WHERE al.approved = 'Yes' AND al.visible ='1'
GROUP BY T.album_id;
```